# Passing in a list object into lapply in R

Tags: r, list, loops, vectorization, lapply

```
library(rpart)
# Fit 3 models
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
fit2 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis,
              parms = list(prior = c(.65,.35), split = "information"))
fit3 <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis,
              control = rpart.control(cp = 0.05))

# Combine into a single list
input <- list(fit, fit2, fit3)

# Define parameters for `myfun`
newdata <- kyphosis[1:20, -1]
rate <- 0.1

myfun <- function(mod, newdata, rate){
  if(length(mod) == 1){
    return(0)
  }else apply(sapply(2:length(mod), function(x) rate * predict(mod[[x]], newdata = newdata)), 1, sum)
}
```

I want my final output `mylist` to be a list of length 3. The first entry in the list contains the vector

```
myfun(mod = input[1], newdata = newdata, rate = rate)
```

the second contains

```
myfun(mod = input[1:2], newdata = newdata, rate = rate)
```

and the third contains:

```
myfun(mod = input[1:3], newdata = newdata, rate = rate)
```

Therefore, the final output `mylist` should look like this:

```
> mylist
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
 [1] 0.027932897 0.091563089 0.027932897 0.081616742 0.091563089 0.091563089 0.091563089 0.091563089 0.091563089 0.027932897 0.091563089
[12] 0.091563089 0.081616742 0.081616742 0.091563089 0.091563089 0.091563089 0.091563089 0.091563089 0.081616742 0.072067103 0.008436911
[23] 0.072067103 0.018383258 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.072067103 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.018383258
[34] 0.018383258 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.008436911 0.018383258

[[3]]
 [1] 0.07003816 0.18188567 0.07003816 0.12372201 0.18188567 0.18188567 0.18188567 0.18188567 0.18188567 0.11825548 0.18188567 0.18188567
[13] 0.12372201 0.17193932 0.18188567 0.18188567 0.18188567 0.18188567 0.18188567 0.17193932 0.12996184 0.01811433 0.12996184 0.07627799
[25] 0.01811433 0.01811433 0.01811433 0.01811433 0.01811433 0.08174452 0.01811433 0.01811433 0.07627799 0.02806068 0.01811433 0.01811433
[37] 0.01811433 0.01811433 0.01811433 0.02806068
```

Is there a quick way to do this without using a for loop? I'm trying to use `lapply`, but it gives me an error.

```
> lapply(input, FUN = myfun, newdata = newdata, rate = rate)
 Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Moreover, I am not sure if `lapply` is the right function to use here. I think by using `lapply` , it would pass in `input[[1]]`, `input[[2]]`, and `input[[3]]` into `myfun`. However, I'd like to pass in `input[1]`, `input[1:2]`, and `input[1:3]`.

In this toy example, `input` is a list of 3 `rpart` objects. However, if `input` is of a list of 100 `rpart` objects, I'd like to avoid using a for loop, as that would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lapply`, you can do :

```
lapply(seq_along(input), function(x) 
       myfun(mod = input[seq_len(x)], newdata = newdata, rate = rate))

#[[1]]
#[1] 0

#[[2]]
# [1] 0.0279 0.0916 0.0279 0.0816 0.0916 0.0916 0.0916 0.0916 0.0916 0.0279
#[11] 0.0916 0.0916 0.0816 0.0816 0.0916 0.0916 0.0916 0.0916 0.0916 0.0816
#[21] 0.0721 0.0084 0.0721 0.0184 0.0084 0.0084 0.0084 0.0084 0.0084 0.0721
#[31] 0.0084 0.0084 0.0184 0.0184 0.0084 0.0084 0.0084 0.0084 0.0084 0.0184

#[[3]]
# [1] 0.070 0.182 0.070 0.124 0.182 0.182 0.182 0.182 0.182 0.118 0.182
#[12] 0.182 0.124 0.172 0.182 0.182 0.182 0.182 0.182 0.172 0.130 0.018
#[23] 0.130 0.076 0.018 0.018 0.018 0.018 0.018 0.082 0.018 0.018 0.076
#[34] 0.028 0.018 0.018 0.018 0.018 0.018 0.028
```

Comment: Thanks. If `input` has 100 entries, is using `lapply` still efficient?

Comment: Yes, it should be. Actually I don't see any other alternative to `lapply`, maybe a `for` loop? But that is going to be more or less the same as `lapply`.